# Bind flat parameter list to a nested model in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a model that have additional parameters as nested models. By default ASP.NET Core adds a prefix to all nested models parameters using property name from outer model.

Consider:

```cs
public class InnerModel {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class OuterModel {
    public InnerModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

As a result I get the following endpoint

`GET /path/to/endpoint?model.value=123`.

Is there a simple way to write a model binder that flattens inner models to a flat list similar to what `AsParametersAttribute` from ASP.NET Core 7 does?

Comment: If you don't want to use `model.value`, you can choose to [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0), But i don't think custom model binding is easiler than using model.value directly

Comment: I considered writing a custom model binder, but it looks too much work to me. I suggested this feature to Msft and it got into .NET 8 planning, but maybe there is not so painful way to write a model binder for this right now.